# PostgreSQL: Join two tables by date range with different dates

Tags: postgresql, date, join

I would like to join two tables using a DATE column in each. For analytical purposes I would like to have the many data from the right table joined to the left table as these are data from the same object measured with different granularties but not necessarily on the same day. An example:

```
LEFT TABLE L               RIGHT TABLE R 
|ID|measDate  |someVal|     |ID|measDate  |someOtherVal|
|01|2015-02-14|0.123  |     |01|2015-02-21|22.5        |
|01|2015-03-02|0.332  |     |01|2015-02-22|21          |
|01|2015-03-08|0.222  |     |01|2015-02-23|22.9        |
|01|2015-03-15|0.3231 |     ...some more data
                            |01|2015-02-26|25.8        |
                            |01|2015-03-05|24.4        |
                            |01|2015-03-06|23.9        |
                            |01|2015-03-12|21.7        |
                            |01|2015-03-15|22.2        |
```

Target table after join should be:

```
|ID|measDate  |someVal|someOtherVal|
|01|2015-02-21|0.123  |22.5        |
|01|2015-02-22|0.123  |21          |
|01|2015-02-23|0.123  |22.9        |
...some more data
|01|2015-02-26|0.123  |25.8        |
|01|2015-03-05|0.332  |24.4        |
|01|2015-03-06|0.332  |23.9        |
|01|2015-03-12|0.222  |21.7        |
|01|2015-03-15|0.3231 |22.2        |
```

I'm quite new to PostgreSQL but already heard something about `generate_series()` and `CROSS JOIN`. But maybe some other trick will do that? Would appreciate any hint and vote the good ones :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Explain how you matched 2015-02-14 in L to 2015-02-21 in R.

Comment: The rule can be: If in L is not the exact date for R (which is the case in most of the time), fill up R with the status from the date older than the date given in R. Or: R has the date 2015-02-21. This date is not given in L. If so than go back in time until you find an entry in L: you will find 2015-02-14. Take this one for a join.

Comment: You need to update your question accordingly first. As written your question ignored the most vital part of the logic. Also show why you ignored 2015-03-08 in your results yet used 0.222 value?

Comment: The second part is a good question: I will take alle results from R but not from L. L is only to fill up the values in R. Or to put it differently: I use the 2015-03-08 date from L to fill up all rows in R which have a date between 2015-03-08 and the next date that occurs in L.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your data more (i.e can you have duplicate dates in either table?) If not, a join on `measDate` column would work:

```
select l.ID, l.measeDate, l.somVal, r.someOtherVal
from l, r
where l.measeDate = r.measDate
```

If duplicates *can* exist, then you're going to need to specify some further information about the expected output for these.

Comment: There are no duplicates. But still I'm not sure if your join will work. In many cases the date given in L is not found in R. In that case R should take the values attached to a date in L which is older than the date in R.